# Get an error when trying to populate a telerik ddl at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

How can I populate a telerik drop-down list at page load?

I get the following error(at emphasized line below) when I try to populate dropdownlist:

```
Error: 'data(...)' is null or not an object
```

Here is how I try to populate the telerik ddl:

```
$(function(){
var values = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) { 

values.push({ Text: i, Value: i });
}
****$("#MyDdl").data("tDropDownList").dataBind(values);****
});
```

Tried it this way as well:

```
 $(function(){
    onDataBinding();
    });

function onDataBinding(e) {
        var MyDdl = $('#MyDdl').data('tDropDownList');
        var values = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {  
    values.push({ Text: i, Value: i });
    }
      ****MyDdl.dataBind(values);****
    };
```

But get following undefined error at emphasized line above:

```
Error: 'undefined' is null or not an object
```

Note:
Adding a button and loading the ddl on button click event does populate telerik drop-down list.
Doing it this way works perfectly fine:

```
    $(function(){
   var values = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {             
        values.push({ Text: i, Value: i });
        }
        $("#MyDdl").data("tDropDownList").dataBind(values);            
    });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: dont think the control is fully loaded when you are binding to it..

Comment: @Amitd Is there any way to load telerik ddl's on page load or right after page loads?

Comment: yep see here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/clientsidebinding

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077252/populate-telerik-dropdown-list-using-jquery

Comment: @Amitd I tried it the way shown in Telerik demo, still doesnt populate  ddl after page load

Comment: can you try doing it on a button click then you can be sure that the code is working?

Comment: @Amitd Adding a button works perfectly, it adds the values to the ddl and the ddl and I can select values. Trying to add "onload" event to telerik ddl does add values to it, I can see them when I debug, but the field is static, cant select any values. What could be the issue here?

Comment: hmm strange.. did you directly call the "onDataBinding" fn as shown in ur code? It shouldn't be called directly. should be called from your view.ie. the control will call it..see answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to populate it in DropDownList's OnLoad event handler:

```
.ClientEvents(events => events.OnLoad("ddl_onLoad").OnChange("ddl_onChange")
```

handlers:

```
function ddl_onLoad(e) {

    var ddl = $(this).data('tDropDownList');

    ddl.dataBind([
        { Text: 'Product 1', Value: '1' },
        { Text: 'Product 2', Value: '2', Selected: true },
        { Text: 'Product 3', Value: '3' },
        { Text: 'Product 4', Value: '4' }
    ]);
}

function ddl_onChange(e) {

    //var ddl = $(this).data('tDropDownList');
    console.log(e.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call the onDataBinding() function directly ..try to link it to the client side event of the control.

*View*:

```
   <%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                          .Name("DropDownList")
                          .ClientEvents(events => events
                          .OnDataBinding("onDropDownListDataBinding"))
        %>
```

*JS*:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            function onDropDownListDataBinding(e) {
                    var MyDdl = $('#MyDdl').data('tDropDownList');
                     MyDdl .dataBind([
            { Text: "Product 1", Value: "1" },
            { Text: "Product 2", Value: "2", Selected: true },
            { Text: "Product 3", Value: "3" },
            { Text: "Product 4", Value: "4" },
            { Text: "Product 5", Value: "5" }            
        ]);
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, dont get the 'undefined' error, but telerik ddl becomes static :/

Comment: what do you see in firebug or ie toolbar?is the html populated properly? any errors? check the console for errors also.. btw i updated the code for dropdown list..

Comment: Do you know when the 'OnDataBinding' Event is triggered? Doesnt look like this event is triggered on page load. However, I tried your above code for 'OnLoad' Event but the ddl is still static. No errors in event viewer.

Comment: must be internal to the telerik usercontrol.. are you sure you get no errors etc? did you follow all steps given in the linked question? do they work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077252/populate-telerik-dropdown-list-using-jquery?lq=1 ... may be something is missing in the master file?

Comment: I was able to populate the telerik ddl successfully by populating it other controls OnLoad event. The issue now is, whenever I add a client event to the telerik ddl, it makes it static/disable. But once I change the ddl to combobox it behaves normally and I am able to add client events.

Comment: do you have some style that gets(or its missing) applied to the ddl? or may be missing js files?  maybe you can link this question in telerik's forum..they are in much better position to answer this.

Comment: Dont think its missing any JS file, as it works perfectly fine without client events, and the client event function is in the same file as my other JS functions. Yea, I did that, no response yet. Is this working for you? When you add a client event to a telerik ddl does it behave normally for you?

Comment: sorry i haven't used telerik ddl yet.Is it possible to make your implementation live on some server or share your solution(just ddl part) ? May be then someone will be able to look at it properly. also does it happen on all browsers? different jquery versions?